# Android equivalent of "/dev/stdout" and "/dev/stderr"

Tags: android, shell, scripting, output

I realize that the files /dev/stdout and /dev/stderr do not exist on an unrooted Android device. I'm okay with that -- but I need *some* way to redirect input/output in my shell-scripts --- including redirecting  output to  output.

Is there anywhere on the Android filesystem an *equivalent* of these missing special-files? If there is, I can design my scripts to automatically use them rather than their traditional equivalents when running on Android --- but only if such files exist.

So does anyone know of Android equivalents of these special-files?

Comment: Hi, I have the same issue, in script: <cmd> 2>&1 >> outfile, but then checking outfile I don't see the errors. what's the solution ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you are looking for the replacement of /dev/stdout and /dev/stderr, use /proc/self/fd/1 and /proc/self/fd/2 respectively (actually, in linux, /dev/stdout and /dev/stderr are symlink to those files).  It works for me on my Galaxy S4.

Comment: Thank you very much! Sorry it took me so long to thank you -- it's just been a while since I last checked StackOverflow. I had kinda given up on this question ever being answered --- but I'm so glad you answered it! Thanks.

Comment: Hi, I have the same issue, in script: <cmd> 2>&1 >> outfile, but then checking outfile I don't see the errors. what's the solution ?

Comment: As far as I know your issue is is not related to this, but you can fix it by "CMD >> outfile 2>&1".  The order is very important.